# Visual Studio 2010 DLL usage issue?

Tags: c#

I have camera capture application written in Silverlight 5 using Visual Studio 2010. The problem is:

[image]

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you add the dll references to the project?

Comment: Any warnings in the error list? They will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Make sure that you have the dll in your project source. Make sure that the dll is referenced by expanding references in the project tree.

Comment: For example one of the error message is: Error 6 The type or namespace name 'FluxJpeg' could not be found

Comment: Agree with all answers. You should also learn to use the VS "Errors" window, its content will be more helpful than a red wave under a word on a screenshot ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've searched the missing assembly and it seems that the assembly you're missing is a `nuget package`

What you can do to fix this is to restore the package by Right Clicking the Solution and clicking Restore Packages.

Or go to

[image]

Paste the url `Install-Package Flux.Jpeg.Core` on the window that will show.

Another way is doing it by right clicking the solution and searching for the package. Here is another visual guide.

[image]

[image]

Select the project you want the package to be added.

[image]

Here is the Nuget Package URL: [FluxJpeg.Core, FJCore, JPG Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flux.Jpeg.Core/)

Comment: yes I found this package but, How can I use it? because I am beginner for C# coding. can you help me?

Comment: @ensberiyu: On the page that DevEstacion linked to, follow the link to `Package Manager Console`, read the page ("Finding and Installing a NuGet Package Using the Package Manager Console"), reach enlightenment and return if you have any further questions.

Comment: @ensberiyu I've added another option for you to do, you can actually select projects you want the references to be added. If you want to get deeper on nuget packages i suggest you research more about its features

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a reference. So, obviously, the list of prerequisites you got is incomplete.

So you have two options:

- Ask the developer who wrote the application where you can get the required DLL and add it to your project references.
- Google for the name of the reference (`FluxJpeg`), note that it can be downloaded freely via NuGet, and do so.

Comment: for example: Error 6 The type or namespace name 'FluxJpeg' could not be found